# "Maximum point lies on a curve" implies tangential derivative is zero there.

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

Given a **differentiable** function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, suppose that it has a local maximum at the point $(x_0,y_0)$. Let $\gamma$ be a smooth curve passing through $(x_0,y_0)$. Does it follow that the directional derivative of $f$ in a direction tangent to the curve at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is zero?

How do I prove this? Heuristically, I will say that since the maximum point lies on a curve the "derivative along the curve" is zero. But how do I state this  mathematically? Also, is there some deeper geometric insight behind this?

EDIT: 'differentiable' added.

Comment: Hint 1:  If you consider the function $g=f\circ \gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to\Bbb{R}$, and suppose $\gamma(0)=(x_0,y_0)$, then zero is a local maximmum of $g$. What happens if you differentiate it?

Comment: Hint 2: Do you remember that $df(v)=\langle\nabla f,v\rangle$ and $D_vf=\langle\nabla f,v\rangle$?

Comment: It doesn't even follow that the directional derivative exists.

Comment: @Chilango Anything cool happens when the function is non-differentiable?

Comment: I'd be interested in how the concept of directional derivative might exist in a weak sense and as a trace on the curve.